# AmCharts - Line Chart Overflowing graph container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amcharts

I am trying to get a line graph to display correctly on my site, but for some reason it wants to overflow the graph container. I have tried reset the box-sizing to initial, setting overflow hidden on all child elements of the graph and nothing seems to be working. I have no idea why this is happening and was wondering if anyone had come across this issue before themselves?

I've added an image below of what I am currently getting and underneath that, the object that is being used to set up the line graph.

[image]

```
{
"type": "serial",
"theme": "light",
"marginRight": 80,
"autoMarginOffset": 20,
"marginTop": 7,
"dataProvider": queryData.data.result,
"valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "position": "left"
}],
"mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
"graphs": [{
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonText": "[[value]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "title": "red line",
    "valueField": "value",
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
    "balloon": {
        "drop": true
    }
}],
"chartScrollbar": {
    "autoGridCount": true,
    "graph": "g1",
    "scrollbarHeight": 40
},
"chartCursor": {
    "limitToGraph": "g1"
},
"categoryField": "name",
"dataDateFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY  HH:NN:SS",
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true
},
"export": {
    "enabled": true
}
}
```

Comment: This might be happening if you have `<base href>` set on your web page. If you do, try adding this line `AmCharts.baseHref = true;`

Comment: @martynasma Thanks for the tip. I've added that line of code, but it is still overflowing the graph container. I've also copied the object directly from the demo on the AmCharts site and it's having the exact same problem. You can view the image [here](http://s24.postimg.org/drm3n5tlh/overflowing_chart_2.jpg)

Comment: So do you have base href on your page? Are you using the latest version of amCharts?

Comment: There is a base href on the page which has a value of `"/umbraco"` which I can't control as I am working in a framework that requires it. The version I'm using is 3.17.3

Comment: Then adding `AmCharts.baseHref = true;` should do it. Make sure that this  line goes **before** any other chart code.

Comment: That's fixed it! Thanks so much! Originally I thought I was adding this to the object of properties itself which is why it wasn't working, but now it is!

Comment: Awesome. I'll add this as an answer as well, so that other people might find it more easily if they hit the same roadblock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be happening if you are using `<base href>` directive on your web page. In those cases references to masking filters in SVG do not work properly, hence lines protruding from plot area.

To avoid that simply add the global [`baseHref`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#baseHref) setting line to your code:

```
AmCharts.baseHref = true;
```

Please note that this must be a standalone line (not a part of chart config) and go **before** any of the code that creates charts.