# amcharts serial line out of borders when zoomed

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

I've a straightforward serial chart drown with amchart library, it renders correctly on IE11 and chrome. When I zoom in everything is fine with IE11, while lines go out of borders with chrome.

IE11

[image]

CHROME

[image]

I've tried to remove all css and any line of code that personalize color and other graphical settings from amchart javascript object but nothing changes, as soon as I add the chartScrollbar any zoom attempt end up in lines out of borders.

Does someone know if this is a bug of amchart? Or any resources where I can look for a workaround? In the official documentation I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Seems like a resize problem to me. Can you provide a fiddle so we can take a look into it?

Comment: @PierreDuc I was just building one, meanwhile I found the solution. The responsible was `<base href>` in the `<head>` section. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418017/amcharts-line-chart-overflowing-graph-container?rq=1